# How to specify a windows path in Vertica Copy Local statement

Tags: windows, vertica

I am using a copy statement to copy data from a csv file on my machine to a Vertica table. But I couldn't find anyway to specify the windows path in the query.
The example on myVertica is

```
copy lcopy_table from local '/home/test.csv' WITH DELIMITER '|' DIRECT
```

Since I am using a window machine, my `test.csv` file is located at `c:\test.csv`. Does anyone know how to specify the path in the query?

Thanks.

Comment: What happened when you tried to specify the path as is?

Answer (score 0):

Use a common backslash paths.

For example:

```
COPY lcopy_table
(id, …)
FROM LOCAL 'C:\test.csv'
DELIMITER ','
SKIP 1
EXCEPTIONS 'con';
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using below syntax to import csv files hosted on windows machines into vertica:

```
copy lcopy_table from LOCAL 'C:/csvdata/test.csv' delimiter ',' NULL as '\N' ENCLOSED by '"';
```

So windows path need to use forward slashes `/` instead of back slashes `\`.